# Databricks "extraneous input expecting EOF" error

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

This took me a while to figure out so I thought I'd share to save someone else the pain. This is obviously dummy code to illustrate the issue.

This doesn't work:

```
%sql

Select 'A' as A -- I won't need this
  , '1' as B;

Select 'Magic';
```

Error message:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
extraneous input 'Select' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 4, pos 0)

== SQL ==
Select 'A' as A -- I won't need this
  , '1' as B;

Select 'Magic';
^^^
```

This does work:

```
%sql

Select 'A' as A -- I wont need this
  , '1' as B;

Select 'Magic';
```

And the difference in the single-quote in the comment on line 3.

Answer (score 2):

When you use single-quote in the comment, you need to pass the comment in double quotes.

**Example:** `-- I won't need this` it should be `-- "I won't need this"`

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. –